# How to merge multiple rows into single in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for some idea to 'merge' multiple rows into single one

Lets say I have such table:

```
ID |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
____________________________
 1 |  x  |  y  |null |  z  |
 2 |null |  z  |null |  x  |
 3 | p   |  w  | a   |null |
 4 | o   |null | k   |null |
```

Now I need to apply changes from all rows with lower ID to each row.
The first row is a base so it should look that:

```
1 |  x  |  y  |null |  z  |
```

Now, for the second row, I need to take the first row and apply changes (if a column is not null) from the second. The second row should look like that:

```
2 |  x  |  z  |null |  x  |
```

Third row - take the first row, apply changes from second and from third:

```
3 |  p  |  w  |  a  |  x  |
```

Fourth row - take the first row, apply changes from second, third and forth:

```
4 |  o  |  w  |  k  |  x  |
```

So the output should look like that:

```
1 |  x  |  y  |null |  z  |
2 |  x  |  z  |null |  x  |
3 |  p  |  w  |  a  |  x  |
4 |  o  |  w  |  k  |  x  |
```

Is there any Oracle feature that can be used for that?

Comment: looking at previous rows is a LAG function - you can use that to get both values and do some logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use hierachical query:

```
CREATE TABLE abcd(
  id int,
   A  varchar2(10),
   B varchar2(10),  
   C varchar2(10),  D varchar2(10)
);

insert all
  into abcd values(1,'x','y',null,'z')
  into abcd values(2,null,'z',null,'x')
  into abcd values(3,'p','w','a',null)
  into abcd values(4,'o',null,'k',null)
select 1 from dual;

commit;
```

---

```
WITH qq(id, a,b,c,d) AS(
   SELECT id, a,b,c,d FROM abcd WHERE id = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT x.id, 
          coalesce( x.a, qq.a ),
          coalesce( x.b, qq.b ),
          coalesce( x.c, qq.c ),
          coalesce( x.d, qq.d )
   FROM qq
   JOIN abcd x ON x.id = qq.id + 1
)
SELECT * FROM qq;

       ID A          B          C          D         
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 x          y                     z         
         2 x          z                     x         
         3 p          w          a          x         
         4 o          w          k          x
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [the `last_value()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST_VALUE.html) for this, with the `ignore nulls` option:

```
last_value(a) ignore nulls over (order by id)
```

will give you the last not-null value seen in the `a` column, up to the current ID (using the default window); so you can repeat that for each column you want to 'merge':

```
select id,
  last_value(a) ignore nulls over (order by id) as a,
  last_value(b) ignore nulls over (order by id) as b,
  last_value(c) ignore nulls over (order by id) as c,
  last_value(d) ignore nulls over (order by id) as d
from your_table
order by id;
```

With your sample data as a CTE:

```
with your_table (id,  a,  b,  c,  d) as (
            select 1, 'x', 'y', null, 'z' from dual
  union all select 2, null, 'z', null,'x' from dual
  union all select 3, 'p', 'w', 'a', null from dual
  union all select 4, 'o', null, 'k', null from dual
)
select id,
  last_value(a) ignore nulls over (order by id) as a,
  last_value(b) ignore nulls over (order by id) as b,
  last_value(c) ignore nulls over (order by id) as c,
  last_value(d) ignore nulls over (order by id) as d
from your_table
order by id;

        ID A B C D
---------- - - - -
         1 x y   z
         2 x z   x
         3 p w a x
         4 o w k x
```

Comment: Excellent. Tomorrow will test which solution is faster (hierarchical query vs last_value). Thank you very much :)

Comment: Well... in my view I have > 100 columns like A,B,C,D. I'm getting ORA-01467 if i have more than ~20 
last_value(x) ignore nulls over (order by id) as x,
statements.

Solution itself is brilliant but not for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `LAST_VALUE` you can also use `COALESCE` and `LAG`.

**Oracle Setup**:

A small PL/SQL script to create a table with a pre-defined number of columns and populate it with 10 rows of random data that is has a 50% chance to be `NULL`.

```
--DROP TABLE table_name;
--DROP SEQUENCE table_name_seq;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  num_columns INT := 5;
  ct  CLOB := 'CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT';
  ins CLOB := 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( table_name_seq.nextval';
  val CLOB := 'SELECT id';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. num_columns LOOP
    ct  := ct || ', c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' ) || ' INT';
    ins := ins || ',' || CHR(10) || '  CASE WHEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE < .5 THEN NULL ELSE TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, 100 ) ) END';
    val := val || ',' || CHR(10) || '       COALESCE( c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' ) || ', LAG( c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' ) || ' ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c' || TO_CHAR( i, 'FM00' );
  END LOOP;
  ct  := ct || ' )';
  ins := ins || ' )';
  val := val || CHR(10) || 'FROM   table_name;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ct;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_seq';
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ins;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( val );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

**Results**:

```
        ID        C01        C02        C03        C04        C05
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1                                                       
         2         37         82         85                    21
         3          8                               76         55
         4         98                    66         78           
         5         17                    39                    19
         6         17          3         91                      
         7         76                    42         63         19
         8         18                    95                      
         9         88         24         49                      
        10                    51                    81         49
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id,
       COALESCE( c01, LAG( c01 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c01,
       COALESCE( c02, LAG( c02 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c02,
       COALESCE( c03, LAG( c03 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c03,
       COALESCE( c04, LAG( c04 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c04,
       COALESCE( c05, LAG( c05 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY id ) ) AS c05
FROM   table_name;
```

**Results**:

```
        ID        C01        C02        C03        C04        C05
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1                                                       
         2         37         82         85                    21
         3          8         82         85         76         55
         4         98         82         66         78         55
         5         17         82         39         78         19
         6         17          3         91         78         19
         7         76          3         42         63         19
         8         18          3         95         63         19
         9         88         24         49         63         19
        10         88         51         49         81         49
```

Change the `num_columns` value to 99 and you can see it working on a table with 100 values without any issues.